# PHP/MYSQL group by column with 2 joined tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table named "class" with field "section", the section field is joined in "section" table and "course" table. Now i want to display all distinct "section" and group it with "course":

```
Course 1  
    -Section 1  
    -section 2  

Course 2  
    -section 3  
    -section 4
```

here is my query code

```
return $this->_db->select("
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        class.section,
                        section.id,
                        section.code,
                        section.name AS sectionname,
                        section.`year`,
                        section.minenrollee,
                        course.code,
                        course.name AS coursename
                    FROM
                        class
                        Inner Join section ON class.section = section.id
                        Inner Join course ON section.course = course.id
                    WHERE
                        class.period =  '".$period."'
                    GROUP BY
                        section.course
                    ORDER BY
                        section.`year` ASC,
                        section.code ASC
                    ");
```

this is my php code. can anyone help me. thanks in advance

```
//GET DISTINCT SECTION IN CLASS
        $sections = $this->model->getDistinctsections(Session::get('period'));
        $list = array();
        foreach ($sections as $r) {
            $list[$r->coursename][$r->id]['coursename'] = $r->coursename;
        }
        print_r($list);
```

Comment: What are you grouping anything? You aren't doing any for of aggregation.

Comment: i want to group it by course which is joined by sections, then display all sections under that course

Comment: The `group by` clause is for aggregation. Not display in your PHP code.

Comment: what would be the best way to achieve it then? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your data should be returning properly as is. That being said, a statement like `print_r()` will never return the data grouped into a nice, "grouped" list. That's not its job; you'll have to do that on your own.

To get a result you want, you'll need to loop through your data. If a column you're grouping on is the same as the column from the previous row, then you don't need to write it to the table again. Since this isn't a coding service, I'll give you an example data set, and you can work from there.

**Example Data:**

```
Company | Department | Employee
-------------------------------
A       | Accounting | John
A       | Accounting | Bill
A       | Billing    | Jane
A       | Billing    | Debra
```

To print this data into a table, grouping on `Company` and `Department`, we need to loop through the data.

**Rough algorithm:**

1. If the previous `Company` is null or doesn't match the current row's value, then print the `Company` value.
2. If the previous `Department` is null or doesn't match the current row's value, then print the `Department` value.
3. Print the value of `Employee`
4. If this isn't the last record, go to step 1.

Following this algorithm should pretty easily get you to a display like

```
Company | Department | Employee
-------------------------------
A       | Accounting | John
        |            | Bill
        | Billing    | Jane
        |            | Debra
```

Minor adaptations from you can make it prettier. :)